# Form validations not working on Microsoft edge, file input is always invalid

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, angular-validation

I have used reactive form validations for angular 6 the form validations are working perfectly on chrome and fire-fox but when I tried it on the edge and after debugging I found that input type file is always has the class ng-invalid in it.

I am unable to find any help on that. I am using form validation to enable disable the submit button and It is disabled always because the field input-type-file is always invalid. I have not done something different it is simple reactive form validations.

Html code

```
<form [formGroup]="accountForm" (ngSubmit)="onAccountSave()" >
```

```
<div class="form-group required col-md-3">
     <label class="control-label mb-10 text-left">Photo Back</label>
    <input type="file" placeholder="Photo" formControlName="photo_back" (change)="onBackFileChanged($event)" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-12">
   <input [disabled]="this.accountForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save">
</div>
```

Ts code

```
 this.accountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      // other fields .....
      photo_back : ['', Validators.required],

    });
```

polyfill.ts

```
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

Comment: Did you include IE features in polyfills.ts file?

Comment: @FedorPatutinskiy I didn't can you tell me where to add it?

Comment: Are you using angular cli for your project?

Comment: @FedorPatutinskiy yes

Comment: Than after you created application you should have polyfills.ts file. And there is a part inside this file where you just have to uncommnet some lines in case you want to use the app in IE.

Comment: I had un-commented all the files that are related to IE but still it is not working validation on other fields are working but only file field validations are not working.  @FedorPatutinskiy I have updated the questions with polyfill.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet due to my low score but I wanted to tell you there is a bug in IE11 (and maybe Edge, too) which marks every formcontrol as dirty if it has a placeholder property. Please try to remove the placeholder Property and test if the form is still invalid in real "pristine" status.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to [this sample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/glxvpdmppvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofile-editor%2Fprofile-editor.component.html) and try to add the required property in the input file:

```
<form [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" required>
  </label>

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```